# How to find minimum route with 3 variables

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a problem where given an undirected graph, to go from one node to the other, the edge has 3 variables (time to move from n1 to n2, distance from n1 to n2, cost from n1 to n2).

Now we have a car that has the following information (time to arrive at the destination, the distance it can move, money or profit)

Given a start and end node, how to find the best route that maximize profit, in other words with minimum cost.

Comment: Checkout Floyd-Warshall algo with time and distance limited. O(N^3)

Comment: I would go with a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) using [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

Comment: If the times and distances are small integers, then an approach [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062622/optimal-path-through-a-matrix-with-multiple-costs-to-consider/62070135#62070135) might be useful. The main difference is that the nodes in that question are a fixed number of steps from the start node, whereas in this question, the nodes are a variable number of steps. Also, you have a three-way tuple: `(time,distance,cost)` which will result in much longer lists for each node.