# Pathfinding Algorithm that can find a path when visiting a node consumes two resources

Tags: graph, dijkstra, a-star

I am trying to create a solver for a puzzle in a web game. The simplest explanation is, I have a 2d grid where visiting each tile and consume different amounts of 2 resources and if either reaches 0 then the path is invalid.

I was trying to use dijkstra's algo to build this but was having trouble because to get to each node you don't know if spending more of one resource will allow better paths in the future.

I've tried to just check all paths with some optimizations but that takes too long even for fairly small boards.

Comment: A* is the way to go.  Use the simple linear distance for the heuristic to choose the next step ( probably manhatten for a 2D grid - need more details ).  On each step calculate the resources to find if you need to backtrack.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062622/). Some nodes will need to be visited multiple times because different paths reach the node with different combinations of resources. The number of visits can be limited by rejecting a visit that reaches a node with less of both resources (compared to a previous visit).

Comment: Looks like "weight constrained shortest path problem" on grid with bi-directed edges (put weights on the incoming edges to a vertex/tile corresponding to its resources). There is no efficient algorithm known in general case (and NP-hardness was proved), not sure about the grid.